# Class instantation and method in same instruction?

Tags: c#

In php, it is possible to directly call a method on a newly created class instance.

```
(new MyClass())->classMethod();
```

Is it possible to do this in C#?

Comment: Yes, did you try it?

Comment: Why, though? If a class is only useful for one method then it isn't making good use of instance-state and it probably should be a static method.

Comment: @Dai, calling instance methods is useful, if you just need a result (as return value or change done by method to one of reference types you pass in, e.g. as constructor parameter or using initializers).

Comment: @Sinatr "calling instance methods" is not _inherently_ useful. My complaint is that if an instance is constructed for the purpose of invoking a single method then that hints at a bad object class design because the same could be accomplished via a `static` method _without_ the requisite GC heap allocation caused by `new`. (This criticism only applies if you're the author of the type in-question - if you're just getting-by with someone else's library then you have my sympathy).

Comment: @Dai, I can't recall right now exact method, but it was even useful with framework methods. I think something with formatters.

Comment: My usecase was this:

commandExecuter.executeCommand(new AbstractCommand().setCommandValue(xyz));

I'm working in Unity and using a command system to avoid other objects directly interacting with my player.

Comment: @Sinatr I'll admit that _one_ use-case for the same syntax is when using a generic type parameter constrained to `struct, new()` as an ugly workaround for emulating "static interfaces", however the `new` operator in that case does not cause a heap-allocation because it's a value-type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, possible, although I am not sure why you need to do it (it is not recommended).

```
new MyClass().CallMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it was actually my use case that cause the problem, i was giving the call as argument to another method and forgot to return the instance after the call, so i tought the issue was with the chaining. I feel stupid now but it happens, for my defense i googled it first but probably wasn't using the right terms.